# Is there any way to predict the amount of "carries" one could get by doing a sum?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-arithmetic

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_(arithmetic)

Definition of carry in Wikipedia

I'm guessing the answer is no but just to be sure I wanted to know of there is a way to predict the amount of carry overs one can get by doing a sum in base 10.

Given a natural number $a$, for example, can I predict the amount of carry overs I will get by doing $ a^2 + 2a +1$? I want to know if it is possible to do this without actually computing the sum.

Thanks in advance

Edit: To clarify, the number of carries in a sum indicates the amount of times one position adds 10 or more. I'm finding this hard to explain so here goes an example:

When you were at school you were probably taught to sum by adding in each position, and if the sum of the numbers in that position exceeds 10, you "carry" a 1 to the next position to the left, leaving in the original position the rightmost digit of your sum.

So for example 5+6 has 1 carry since you add two numbers in the $10^0$ position and carry a 1 to the $10^1$ position

Comment: Can you define a "carry"?

Comment: Would that count have to include the number of carries for computing $2a$ or $a^2$?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. No, do not include those carries. Just the ones from doing the original sum. I'm trying to check whether computing those carries would change something

Comment: So you're looking for corresponding digits in $a^2$ and $2a$ either where the sum of the two digits is greater than $9$ or where the sum is exactly $9$ and there is a carry from the next place to the right. My guess is that there is not a way to do this that is significantly more efficient in the general case than actually doing the sum. (Possibly in actual computing there is a way to gain a few processing cycles by ignoring some of the results of the addition and looking _only_ at the carry.)

Comment: Yeah I was guessing that actually predicting this for any number a would be too good to be true. I guess I could always try to do some calculations heuristically with a pc.

Comment: It holds that the number of carries when adding $x+y$ in base $b$ is $(d_b(x)+d_b(y)-d_b(x+y))/(b-1)$ where $d_b$ is the sum of digits in base $b$. This is because each time you do a carry, the sum of digits increases by $1$ but decreases by $b$. (See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430293/5821790).) I'm not sure if the digit sum of $a^2$ or $2a$ has any patterns.